# DVR & Port Forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, dvr

My dvr http port is 80 by default. So, in my router, I forwarded port 80 to my dvr ip address(internal ip). I was able to view my dvr online through my public ip(static). Now I want to stop this. I deleted the port forwarding from my router. But still my dvr is opening when I access my public ip(static) outside of my network. Plz suggest. Why my router is still diverting my public ip(static) directly to my dvr?

Comment: Sometimes a router restart is needed to get rules updated properly.

Comment: After deletion of rule for port 80 I restarted the router many times. But canyouseeme.org is also seeing my port 80 on my public ip(static). Dvr is also opening directly if i access my public ip from outside of my network.

Comment: Since you haven't published any diagnostic data it is impossible to tell. The question is simply too broad. I don't even know for sure whether port forwarding was needed in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a router bug or perhaps may have enabled DMZ (demilitarized zone) if that is a feature in your router, this would disable all firewall features of the router. You might want to check your firewall settings, possibly add a rule to block port 80 and test again or forward port 80 to a non-existing IP address so that any traffic to 80 leads to nowhere.

If all else fails you could try resetting the router to factory defaults.